# Unable to connect to http://localhost:8080/openacs/acs getting 500 internal error for Openacs server

Tags: java, jboss

Installed
Jboss 4.2.2.GA

java -version
java version "1.5.0_20"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 1.5.0_20-b02, mixed mode)

Installed Openacs code from
https://github.com/ethanpeng/openacs

and
https://osdn.net/projects/sfnet_libreacs/downloads/OpenACS/openacs-bin-0.5.0.3.zip/

But still facing same issue on both link

Getting error as below
500 Internal error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openacs.ACSServlet.RunConfigurator(ACSServlet.java:632)
    at org.openacs.ACSServlet.processRequest(ACSServlet.java:522)
    at org.openacs.ACSServlet.doGet(ACSServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```